# Timestamp array not displaying in custom table view swift

Tags: ios, arrays

I have an array of dates that I would like to show in a custom table view, which has how much you spent, and the date you spent this amount. I created two different arrays, one for the amount they spent, and the other array which saves the times at which they spent the money.

I don't get any compile errors on my code, but when I run the app, it crashes and at the line `cell.dateLbl.text = AddSubtractMoneyController.datesArray[indexPath.row]` and gives me this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

any ideas of why this could be happening?

```
class SpendingHistoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard


@IBOutlet weak var tableViewSpending: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var youSpentLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableViewSpending.delegate = self
    self.tableViewSpending.dataSource = self

    //GETS user defaults that was set in ADDSUBTRACTMONEY VC - and then sets the default to Array- then gets total

    let moneySpentArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "moneySpent") as? [Double] ?? [Double]()
    let arraySum = moneySpentArray.reduce(0.0, +)
    AddSubtractMoneyController.moneySpentArray = moneySpentArray
    youSpentLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", arraySum)



    let spendingDateArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "spendingDateArray") as? [String] ?? [String]()

    AddSubtractMoneyController.datesArray = spendingDateArray


    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return(AddSubtractMoneyController.moneySpentArray.count)

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 75

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableViewSpending.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! SpendingHistoryTableViewCell

    cell.spentAmountLbl.text = String(format: "%.2f", AddSubtractMoneyController.moneySpentArray[indexPath.row])


    cell.dateLbl.text = AddSubtractMoneyController.datesArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}



class AddSubtractMoneyController: NSObject {




let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

static var moneySpentArray:Array<Double> = []
static var savingsArray: Array <Double> = []
static var daysArray: Array <Int> = []
static var datesArray: Array <String> = []

//let savingsArraySaved = "savingsArraySaved"


class func addToMoneySpentArray( amountISpent: Double) {

    moneySpentArray.append(amountISpent)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(moneySpentArray, forKey: "moneySpent")

}

class func addToSavingsArray( finalDailySavedAmount: Double) {

    savingsArray.append(finalDailySavedAmount)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(savingsArray, forKey: "savingsTotalArray")

    //print(savingsArray)
}

class func addDayInSavingsArray(dayCount: Int){
    daysArray.append(dayCount)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(daysArray, forKey: "dayCountArray")

}

class func addDateToMoneySpentArray(date: String) {

    datesArray.append(date)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(datesArray, forKey: "spendingDateArray")

    print(datesArray)


}
```

Comment: looks like AddSubtractMoneyController.datesArray and AddSubtractMoneyController.moneySpentArray counts are different. looks like your data stored in UserDefaults is corrupted. 
put a breakpoint in viewdidload and check the count. and try uninstalling the app and installing again.

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice! You’re 100% correct. They weren’t adding up. How did you spot that out by the way? For future references. Good eyes !!

Comment: error "Index out of range" that literally means you are trying to get data from an array at an index which doesn't exist.
Also find the source of data corruption, it will happen again.

Comment: @GokulG the problem was- I created the money spent array first and began putting info into it. Then I created the dates array, without deleting the app. So the counts were off like you said which caused the array out of index error. Both of the arrays share one custom table view cell. So I’m guessing that is the reason, as opposed to having corrupted data. Thank you

Comment: Your code posted here is missing some brackets to close the ends of your classes...

Comment: @GokulG hey so you were right- The data is corrupted again! I am trying my hardest to resolve this issue. Do you have any thoughts based from your experience on how the UserDefaults could be corrupted? This is my logic. A user enters how much they spent - when they click IBAction "go"- i append the specific amount to "moneySpentArray". I  also append the date to the "datesArray". i save them both as a user default in the second class pasted above. and then call them in the SpendingMoneyHistoryVC above. I have no idea where the data can be getting corrupted? Please, any suggestions help thx

Comment: @GokulG never mind my friend! I know EXACTLY why it happened. Figured it out now. Thank you for suggestions and insight !!